# Flutter: exported apk showing a problem with drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I finished my app and exported it. Everything works perfectly fine on the emulator. On my android phone (running Android 10) everything works as well, but only the drawer is being displayed like this:

[image]

Exported the apk using `flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you try running the app in debug mode in your mobile phone instead of emulator. Does the same problem occurs?

Comment: Connecting the phone via USB and firing up the App in debug mode there doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: Anything in the debug console? If not, run the app in release mode on an emulator or physical device using this command `flutter run --release`.

Comment: use `flutter run --profile` on the physical device. It is basically the release mode with some debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter shows gray boxes where an error or exception happens, during development it shows a red box containing the error.

So probably it's not a problem with Flutter.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Flutter isn't showing any errors or warnings. Even when connecting the phone tp PC via USB and launching the app there, it works perfectly fine. So my guess is that it's a problem with exporting the apk

Comment: Have you debugged the app in VSCode? I once encountered something similar and I found some errors in VSCode's debug console. The app was fine during development but it showed a gray box in release mode. I fixed those errors and the gray box was gone. @Nerdenberg